# Can't select something else the starts with the same in Select2 dropdown

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I have a select2 dropdown in my application. Zipcodes and cities are loaded into this select. When I type "2800" I get "2800 Mechelen" and "2800 Walem" because the two cities have to same zipcode.

When I've selected "2800 Mechelen", I can't select "2800 Walem" anymore. But it's still possible to select something else that has an other zipcode.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed this issue by removing the  tags in the  when you click on the select2 span element.

```
$('span.select2').click(function(e){
    if ($('select#zipcode_belgium').has('option').length == 0) {
        //no options
    } else {
        //has options
        $('select#zipcode_belgium').empty();
    }
});
```